# Pandas, how to add Series to DataFrame column, where series index matches a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, and a Series.  They a sample is:

```
b = [
        {'key': 'c', 'value': 10},
        {'key': 'a', 'value': 5},
        {'key': 'b', 'value': 3},
        {'key': 'd', 'value': 99}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(b)
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} 
series = pd.Series(a)
```

How can I add the values of `series`, to the `value` column in `df` where the index of `series` matches the `key` column of `df`? Note key `d` which isn't in `series` does not change.  For the example above, I want to end up with:

```
result_data = [
        {'key': 'c', 'value': 13},
        {'key': 'a', 'value': 6},
        {'key': 'b', 'value': 5},
        {'key': 'd', 'value': 99}
]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `a` as lookup dict:

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['value'] + a.get(x['key'], 0), axis=1)

print(df[['key', 'sum']])

  key  sum
0   c   13
1   a    6
2   b    5
3   d   99
```

Answer (score 0):

do you care about the index?

```
df = df.set_index('key')
df.add(series, axis=0).fillna(df)

   value
a    6.0
b    5.0
c   13.0
d   99.0
```